# is there a "xdotool" rpm available for Centos Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, yum, rpm, repository

It seems to be extremely difficult to install xdotool
on CentOS because of it's requirements. such as

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools' -y
yum install libXi-devel libXtst-devel libXinerama-devel -y
```

the top one especially is difficult to move to a folder and install
locally. ( without internet ). ( for extra speed ).

Currently I have to run those two commands and then I have to run these
in order to install `xdotool` on CentOS Linux.

```
cat > /etc/ld.so.conf << "EOF"
/usr/local/lib
EOF
# rm -rf xdotool-2.20110530.1
# tar -xvf xdot*
cd xdot*
make install
```

I tried adding `epel` and `rpmforge` repos to my yum and then I searched for `xdotool` nothing was found.

I was wondering if there is a known rpm version so that installing it would be simple on CentOS Linux.

Comment: What version of CentOS are you running? I found a CentOS 6 RPM for it: http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/nux-dextop-i386/xdotool-2.20110530.1-4.el6.nux.i686.rpm.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking closer into it. It looks like `xdotool` is provided by the [epel](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/xdotool-3.20150503.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) repository (the previous source, *Nux dextop*, is now defunct):

```
[root@nctirlwb07 ~]# yum info xdotool
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Available Packages
Name        : xdotool
Arch        : i686
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 2.20110530.1
Release     : 7.el6
Size        : 43 k
Repo        : epel
Summary     : Fake keyboard/mouse input
URL         : http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/
License     : BSD
Description : This tool lets you programmatically (or manually) 
simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and re-size windows, etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

this simple way for install xdotools

```
yum install epel-release -y
yum install xdotool -y
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).